# Composable routing with Spring RouterFunctionDsl

Tags: spring, kotlin, spring-webflux

I am trying to write more composable RouterFunctions where routing details are abstracted to individual classes. I would still like to be able to have a single `myRoutes` function at the root of my application.

Is this possible? If so, what does the syntax for this look like?

**Current State**

```
@Bean
fun myRoutes(): RouterFunction<ServerResponse> {
    return router {
        "/base-url".nest {
            "/thing-one".nest {
                GET("/", ::getThingOne)
            }
            "/thing-two".nest {
                GET("/", ::getThingTwo)
            }
        }
    }
}

fun getThingOne(serverRequest: ServerRequest): Mono<ServerResponse> {
    return Mono.empty<ServerResponse>()
}

fun getThingTwo(serverRequest: ServerRequest): Mono<ServerResponse> {
    return Mono.empty<ServerResponse>()
}
```

**Desired State**

```
@Bean
fun myRoutes(): RouterFunction<ServerResponse> {
    return router {
        "/base-url".nest {
            ThingOneClass.getRouting()
            ThingTwoClass.getRouting()
        }
    }
}

object ThingOneClass {
    fun getRouting() {
        "/thing-one".nest {
            GET("/", ::getThingOne)
        }
    }

    fun getThingOne(serverRequest: ServerRequest): Mono<ServerResponse> {
        return Mono.empty<ServerResponse>()
    }
}

object ThingTwoClass {
    fun getRouting() {
        "/thing-two".nest {
            GET("/", ::getThingTwo)
        }
    }

    fun getThingTwo(serverRequest: ServerRequest): Mono<ServerResponse> {
        return Mono.empty<ServerResponse>()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out how to accomplish this. The method in the abstracted routes object must return a function that conforms to `RouterFunctionDsl.() -> Unit` and then the function needs to be invoked  (`()` or `.invoke(this)`)

```
@Bean
fun myRoutes(): RouterFunction<ServerResponse> {
    return router {
        "/base-url".nest {
            // Option 1 `.invoke(this)`
            ThingTwoClass.getRouting().invoke(this)
            // Option 2 `()` - implicitly call invoke(this)
            ThingOneClass.getRouting()()
        }
    }
}

object ThingOneClass {
    fun getRouting(): RouterFunctionDsl.() -> Unit {
        return {
            "/thing-one".nest {
                GET("/", ::getThingOne)
            }
        }
    }

    fun getThingOne(serverRequest: ServerRequest): Mono<ServerResponse> {
        return Mono.empty<ServerResponse>()
    }
}

object ThingTwoClass {
    fun getRouting(): RouterFunctionDsl.() -> Unit {
        return {
            "/thing-two".nest {
                GET("/", ::getThingTwo)
            }
        }
    }

    fun getThingTwo(serverRequest: ServerRequest): Mono<ServerResponse> {
        return Mono.empty<ServerResponse>()
    }
}
```